# Mealy FSM using SR Flip Flops: pattern detector

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, state-machines, sequence-detector

I was asked to design a Mealy FSM using SR Flip Flops to detect a pattern.
It should detect if the pattern is either '1001' or '0110'.

I was able to make the state diagram (I have attached the image), but I am confused about forming the state table and solving it with K- Map. It has a total of 7 states (so I need 3 FFs right?), and the inputs can either be 0 or 1, so that's a total of 5 variables then (please correct me if I am wrong).

So in that case, is this to be solved using a 5 variable K - Map?

[image: state diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the FSM diagram for state `E`.  Both transitions out of state `E` show the same input/output values, but they should be different.

Assuming the customary notation of `input/output`, both transitions show `0/0`.  One of the transitions should show input=1, like `1/0`.

There is a similar mistake for state `B`.  Both transitions out of the state show the same value: `1/0`.

> It has a total of 7 states (so I need 3 FFs right?)

Yes, if you have 7 states, you can encode those states with 3 FFs.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't notice that. Thanks for your help! So, I have to do it using a 5 variable K-Map, I guess.